# Regular Disk Backup Vs. Hyper-V Backup

Tags: backup, hyper-v

I have a Server 2012-r2 environment where the hard disks are backed up regularly. In the machine I also have two or three VM running at a time. I was wondering if the entire disk backup is enough to recover the VMs (in case of a failure) or is there another technical reason for investing in a separate Hyper-V VM backup tool.

Comment: Are you backing up the raw disk images? If so, how? What product do you use? Please add some details.

Comment: How are the hard disks backed up? With VSS aware/capable backup software?

Comment: I am currently using a product called "Veeam Endpoint Backup" that creates a shadow copy and then backs up the entire drive. Previously I was using "Windows Backup" and doing the same thing (meaning I was not doing the VM backup separately but was doing the entire disk backup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The volumes hosting the VMs contain a lot of things.  The VHDs will be the bulk of that, but there will also be things which you don't need to back up, like the file reserved for paging the guest VM (if you have Dynamic Memory enabled.)

Furthermore, if you just back up the volumes (and I doubt that's what Veeam is doing) then you get an image of the VHDs which may not be internally consistent with respect to what the guest OS was doing.  Mounting those VHDs in the future (either because you restored the VM or because you just want to fish a file out of the VHD) may result in seeing a corrupted file system, leading to a long chkdsk cycle, or a corrupted application, database, etc.

Taking a backup of the VM by asking Hyper-V to do it, which amounts to backing up the VMs instead of the volumes they sit on, will trigger a process of asking the guest VM to come to self-consistent state before the VHDs are snapshotted.  Basically, Hyper-V includes the "Backup Integration Service" which allows it to impersonate the backup application within the guest VM.  It asks the guest to snapshot itself, including any databases, volumes and whatever may exist.  Then at the moment when the guest has flushed everything do its virtual disks, that's when the VHDs are placed in the host snapshot.

Comment: The point regarding corrupted file system with volume backup is interesting. I thought that the shadow copy will help produce a consistent image at a particular point of time. You probably mean that windows applications sometimes keep the file system in inconsistent state while doing operations in the memory. If the backup is taken at that time it will lead to issues?

Comment: If you take a shadow copy of the vhd from the host doesn't help at all since all it really knows is "is file locked,if so finish writes" (very simplified), and has  hyper-v effectively tells the guest " you are getting backed up, create a shadow copy internally"

Comment: Samuel, you need to keep in mind that there are really two file systems that we're interested in here, the one on the host which contains the VHD and the one in the guest.  If you back up the hosting volume, it will take a snapshot and you'll have a coherent hosting volume from which to take the VHD snapshot.  The guest's file system however, will not be consistent.  To get a consistent view of that, you need the guest to bring itself to a consistent state, which is what happens if you ask Hyper-V to back up the VM.

Answer (score 1):

I have never been in a situation where I've had too many backups.  You should have both hyper-v vhd backups and application/data backups.  This will allow you to do the least disruptive restore possible, and recover from data issues without having to recover the whole VM.  If yo have the case where the host fails you are covered there too.